# How to store a div ID value globally

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating an application that uses the same number pad to fill out two separate text style form values using javascript.

I found out how to gather a div ID for use inside of a function (for say toggling the hide value), but I need to save this value somehow so that I can know which field to put the numbers into when they come in.

I tried using a global variable for this, but it does not seem to work as the ID does not seem to be recorded as a String value.

The code that I am using does toggle the show/hide attribute, but if I use an alert box to pop what the variable I am using as storage is it reads `[object HTMLDivElement]`

My script looks like this (bear in mind that I am a noob to javascript).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    <!--
    keypad.display="none";
    //Classes for the numberpad on the text fields.

        var padName = ""; //Storage for the name of the current pad.

        function numPad(field) {
            var pad = document.getElementById("keypad"); //manipulating pad.
            var ref = document.getElementById(field);//gather the field info.
            if (pad.style.display == "block") { //Open or close?
                pad.style.display = "none"; //Blank out.
                padName = "";   
            }
            else {
                pad.style.display = "block";//Set to refer to correct field.
                padname = ref;
                alert (ref); 
            }
        }

        function click(id) {
            var key = document.getElementById(id);
            var total = padName.value();
            if (key == "Backspace") total.slice(0, -1);
            else if (key == "Enter") numPad("blanck");
            else total += key;
            padName.value = total;
        }
    -->
</script>
```

Comment: do you know how to use console.log?

Comment: Never heard of it. is it a storage area?

Comment: @Joseph like I said.... I am a noob to this :P

Comment: pretty easy to use.  (I'll explain using chrome).  use console.log(ref) in your code, open the page in chrome, and press Ctrl-Shift-J.  This will open up a console and you will be able to see that element printed in the console.

Comment: @Andy Same instructions apply for Firefox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// to get the ID by direct property access of the DOM element
var ref = document.getElementById(field).id;
```

and then `ref` stores the ID value.

I would suggest:

```
// create an object to store app-wide settings
// access properties like this: appSettings.propertyName
var appSettings = { padName: "" };

...

var ref = document.getElementById(field).id;
appSettings.padName = ref;
```

to avoid polluting the global namespace.

To get/set the value of the pad, you'll need to do this:

```
// to get
var total = document.getElementById(appSettings.padName).value;

// to set
document.getElementById(appSettings.padName).value = "something";
```

You should read up on DOM objects and properties.

Comment: You'll also need `document.getElementById(appSettings.padName).value = ...` when assigning `total`.

Answer (score 1):

For starters, `ref` is assigned a reference to a DOM element. You are then assigning this reference to `padName`, hence the `[object HTMLDivElement]` alert.

If you just want the ID stored in `padName`, use

```
padName = field;
```

Also, you're mixing cases of `padName`. You have both `padName` and `padname`.

Further, as mentioned in the comments, use the console for debugging. It's much more comprehensive than an alert.

I can't tell what's happening in your `click` function. You seem to be expecting `padName` to be an object of some kind however where the `value()` method and `value` property comes from is anyone's guess (FYI only form elements have `value` properties).

Comment: thanks. I didnt notice the case mixing. The value property is coming from a form text field so I am assuming that this command will grab out any String that is in that field.